# How to get average star rating value (native mongodb & express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

Using Express, and I have a collection in MongoDb `breakfast-tacos` with a field named `rating:`. Trying to calculate the average value of the `rating` field, which is numbers no greater than 5. Attempting to `aggregate` but keep getting `TypeError: db.collection(...).aggregate(...).then is not a function`. New to the aggregation pipeline/mongo, can anyone give an example of how use this to get average value with native mongodb (not mongoose) correctly and an explanation?

My Code:

```
    app.get('/breakfast-rating', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('breakfast-tacos').aggregate([{$group: { "_id": "$ObjectId"}, $avg: {"rating":"$rating" }}])
        .then(results => {
            res.send({ rating: results });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to ascertain the average value of all `rating` fields, you need something as simple as this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "avg",
      avgrating: {
        $avg: "$rating"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

So you code should look like so:

```
    app.get('/breakfast-rating', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('breakfast-tacos').aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "avg",
            avgrating: {
              $avg: "$rating"
            }
          }
        }
      ])
        .then(results => {
            res.send({ rating: results[0].avgrating });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    });
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7zLr3E6FoLh

Comment: I tried your code, but still getting the same aggregate is not a function error. Not sure why though.

Comment: @JasonBryant Strange. Does `db.collection('breakfast-tacos').find(..` throw a similar error?

Comment: I changed to .find() and yes same error. If I replace with ```db.collection('breakfast-tacos').find({}).toArray()``` it works correctly (returns all).

Comment: @JasonBryant Try doing the same with the aggregation then. Apparently, it does not return a promise so `then` is not a function. Try: `db.collection('breakfast-tacos').aggreaget([...]).toArray()`

Comment: @codemoney that makes perfect sense and now problem is solved! Added the above code in comment with ```.toArray()``` and now it is returning correctly. Thank you.